# Travis CI: Cannot find module 'underscore'

Tags: node.js, travis-ci

One of my Github repositories is hooked up to Travis CI so that anytime I make a PR, Travis runs two tests. These include `continuous-integration/travis-ci/push` and `continuous-integration/travis-ci/pr`. The second one always passes, but `continuous-integration/travis-ci/push` fails every time with the message:

> Cannot find module 'underscore'

Any idea what might be the cause of this inconsistent behavior? And any known way to resolve it?

Comment: Googling for this error message suggests [tag:node.js] but it would probably be good if you could add precise details and context to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was a transient issue with Travis. The problem resolved itself after a couple of days.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `underscore` to your package.json `dependencies`.

The easiest way to do so is by running `npm install --save underscore` in your project folder.

Chances are this library is installed on your machine, but is not listed in the package.json, so it isn't available on travis.

You can always run `npm prune` to clean up your local `node_modules` folder of unlisted dependencies.

If this doesn't fix your issue, then read the Travis CI `npm install` log. There might be are an error occurring during the install process, but that'd be unlikely.